# IE11 css table collapses on link hover. Impossible to understand

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the worst and most annoying issue ever! It is driving me mad!!

It only happens in IE11, but I have also tried it on another machine with IE11 and it didnt happen!!

I have a two column page layout, set up with css tables. In the left hand column, there is another 100% height table with two rows, the top one has a 50% height and a vertical-align:top and the lower has a 50% height and a vertical-align:bottom, so that some content remains at the top of the page, and some remains at the bottom.

The right hand column is variable in height, as that is where the page content will be, and the left hand column must resize to fit the screen height.

In firefox, chrome, IE8, etc, this all works fine.

But in IE11, if you hover over a link inside the left hand column, the layout collapses.

[image]

This is the layout I am trying to achieve.

[image]

But this is what happens if you hover over one of the links in the left column!

This makes no sense to me at all, and I cant fix it.

I have tried using CSS table layouts and "old school" tables, but I cant find any way to fix this.

My current code, which is just one of several attempts, is...

```
<div class="fullcontent-wrapper"><div class="fullcontent-tablerow">

<div class="left-wrapper"><div class="left">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<tr><td style="width:350px; height:100%; vertical-align:top; background:#151515;">
left hand top content
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:350px; height:100%; vertical-align:bottom; background:#151515;">
left hand bottom content
</td></tr>
</table>
</div></div>

<div class="right-wrapper"><div class="right">
right hand content
</div></div>

</div></div>
```

And my CSS...

```
.fullcontent-wrapper {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
}
.fullcontent-tablerow {
display: table-row;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.left-wrapper {
display: table-cell;
width: 350px;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
overflow: hidden;
background: #151515;
}
.left {
width: 350px;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 0px;
}
.right-wrapper {
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}
```

If anyone can offer any sort of advice or explanation as to why this happens and a fix for it, I will be eternally grateful!

Or if you have any suggestions on better code to achieve the same desired page layout, then I would also be happy to try that!

Many thanks!

Comment: If this is working fine on other machines with IE11, the first thing I would check is the mode you're running in (i.e. Edge, IE10, IE9, etc.).  You can change that by hitting F12 then selecting "Emulation" from the menu.  You can change a lot of options from there.

Comment: Even if that is a possible "fix", you still probably want to fix the issue for older IE browsers.  Do you have ANY :hover css?  Or any jQuery hover events?  Otherwise you're right, that's a very unusual issue.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all IE plugins/etc? If it happens on one computer but not another, definitely sounds like something's wonky with your IE